# How to ggplot an xts time series in r?

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

The call to plot() below works, while the call to ggplot() does not. I have very poor vision, perhaps I am missing something obvious?

```
library(ggplot2)
n=1000
data <- rnorm(n) #Error in rpois(n) : argument "lambda" is missing, with no default
dates <- seq(as.Date("2017-05-01"),length=n,by= "days")
ts <- xts(x=data, order.by=dates)
plot(ts)
ggplot(ts)
```

Comment: To reproduce the base R plot in `ggplot2` try `autoplot(ts)`. If you are able to then it would be worth reading the `ggplot2` [documentation](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/). The syntax (and philosophy) of creating a plot is quite different to base R.

Comment: autoplot works.  ggplot(df, aes(x = Index, y = data)) + works also. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could do it this way:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(xts)

n <- 1000
data <- rnorm(n)
dates <- seq(as.Date("2017-05-01"), length = n, by = "days")
ts <- xts(x = data, order.by = dates)

# Option1: 
autoplot(ts)


# Option2 using ggplot2
ggplot(df, aes(x = Index, y = data)) + 
  geom_line() +
  labs(x = "Date", y = "Value")
```

[image]